# Sum of digits of a number in C#?

Tags: c#, python, sum, digits

I am trying to write a code that sums the digits of a number and it should work, but I can't find where I am doing it wrong, I have a working code in Python for this and I tried to do it the same way in C# but.. Here are the two codes

Python:

```
number = "12346546"
summ=0
for i in number:
    summ+=int(i)
print summ
```

C#:

```
string num = "2342";
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
{
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(num[i]);
    sum += number;
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Edit: I used the Debugger and I found that when I am converting the numbers they turn out to be completely different numbers, but if I convert the whole string then it is converting correctly... how to fix this?

Comment: Typo in your for loop:  try "i < num.Length" or "i <= num.Length-1"

Comment: -1 -- You didn't even describe your problem. If you get an error *paste* it into the question. If you get an unexpected output *paste* the output you get *and* write the expected output.

Comment: Bakuriu thanks about pointing that out but I actually did at the end of my post the "Edit:", but obviously it was not really necessary since in a few seconds several users told me where my mistake is before I managed to Edit my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`num[i]` is a `char` and [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return the ASCII code of the char instead of the actual numerical value.Use:

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(num[i].ToString());
```

Also change `i < num.Length-1` to `i < num.Length`

**Edit:** To make it more clear here is an example:

```
int n1 = Convert.ToInt32('0'); // Uses Convert.ToInt32(char) result -> 48
int n2 = (int) '0'; // cast from char to int result -> 48
int n3 = Convert.ToInt32("0"); // Uses Convert.ToInt32(string) result -> 0
```

Comment: Yes, thanks I noticed that as soon as I used your converting method, it's working now! :)
Thanks about the ASCII explanation, I was expecting that the reason was something similar.

Comment: Just a clarifying question: num[i].ToString() takes the ith element and converts it to a String on its own making it totally independent from the original string and that's why now its converting correctly?

Comment: @Darkbound yes, when you convert it to string, you are using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx) overload of Convert.ToInt32 and that's why it gives the expected result

Answer (score 3):

replace `Convert.ToInt32(num[i])`

by

```
Convert.ToInt32(num[i].ToString())
```

else, you will get an ascii value... (cause `num[i]` is a `char`)

see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is no null at the end of a C# string, so you don't have to worry about it, and thus do not require the "-1" in your loop. However, there is a much easier way:

```
string num = "2342";
int sum = num.ToCharArray().Select(i => int.Parse(i.ToString())).Sum();
```

This converts the string to a character array, converts them all to ints (returning an `IEnumerable<int>` in the process) and then returns the sum of them all.

Comment: There *is no* null at the end in a C# string.

Comment: @TimS. clarified. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: This will not compile, `int.Parse` expects a `string` type parameter, and you are trying to pass a character. Also, there is no need to do `ToCharArray`, you can apply the LINQ on string as well.

Comment: @Habib, yep, forgot the .ToString on the char. I wasn't aware of the "Sum" function on String, which would be a shorter (though perhaps less clear to those unaware of the function) way of doing the same thing.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, string implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so you will get LINQ with it.

Comment: @Habib, Learn something new every day... Thanks for the information

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToInt32(num[i]);` would give you the ASCII value for the character digit. For example for character `1` you will get `49`.

Use `char.GetNumericValue` like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
{
    int number = (int) char.GetNumericValue((num[i]));
    sum += number;
}
```

You also need to modify your loop to continue till Length, since you are using `<`.

If you want to use LINQ then you can do:

```
int sum = num.Select(r => (int)char.GetNumericValue(r)).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

A one line solution using Linq:

```
string num = "2342";
int sum = num.Sum(c=> Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString()));
```

Here's a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3jt7G6

Comment: I don't see how this would sum the digits

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'd be glad to clarify on what you are not seeing. Take a look at the fiddle

Comment: I see it now, didn't know there was such a function on .String that took a selector like that! Thanks for the fiddle, I might link the String.Sum documentation as well.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET `Sum` is actually an extension method on IEnumerable that's available when you use `System.Linq` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549046(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I didn't know String inherited IEnumerable, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine a few things.

You can select a collection of `char`s from a `string` using Linq ([Sum() is a Linq method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386928%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

You still need to convert those characters into numbers; you can do this by converting a character to a string and parsing that or you can use another built-in method.

```
var sum = num.Sum(i => Char.GetNumericValue(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` is, at its core, just a number. It just happens to be a number representing a character.

Here are some solutions that highlight this:

```
int sum = num.Sum(c => c) - '0' * num.Length;

// or

int sum = 0;    
for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
{
    sum += num[i] - '0';
}
```